# Cannot bind Web Method to jTable

Tags: asp.net, webmethod, jquery-jtable

I am trying to bind jTable with data but my web method is not returning anything. I can see that from Chrome developer console. Here is the code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static object ProductList()
{
    try
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Mercedes", Category = "Cars", Price = 20 });
        products.Add(new Product { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Mercedes", Category = "Cars", Price = 20 });
        products.Add(new Product { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Mercedes", Category = "Cars", Price = 20 });

        return new { Result = "OK", Records = products };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I am just trying to return a simple JSON from a web method from my code behind file. I am not using asmx service or any other service for that matter.

Comment: WebMethod is intended for ASMX services. You could have meant `PageMethod` instead.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. But still it is valid afaik and it should return. Then why is not showing any response?

Comment: Actually I tested the web method with simple `jQuery.ajax()` request and it seems to return as intended. Then the problem has to reside with jTable's request. Advise please.

Comment: I recommend you show your JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. But I solved it. This reference `<script src="Scripts/jtable/extensions/jquery.jtable.aspnetpagemethods.min.js"></script>` is required for data transfer to take place.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, there's also ASP.NET WebAPI, or better yet, ServiceStack.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. A specific file has to be referenced in the html file where the jtable has to be shown. Like below:

```
<script src="Scripts/jtable/extensions/jquery.jtable.aspnetpagemethods.min.js"></script>
```